# Failure in writing a BMP file

Tags: c#, bitmap, image-manipulation, bmp

I am trying to generate a BMP file that has some text. I created a winform application and I can succesfully create the BMP (I displayed it on a picture Box with no problems). However when I save it to a file, I just got a black image.

My code is

```
private void btnNameUsage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

   string name = "Hello how are you";
   string date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(); 

   Graphics thegraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

   string complete = date+"\n"+name ;

   using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
   using (var sf = new StringFormat()
      {
           Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
           LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
       })
        {
         thegraphics.DrawString(complete, font1, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), sf);
         }


   picBoxImage.Image = bmp;  //THIS WORKS

   //thegraphics.Flush();//I am not sure this is necessary and it changes nothing anyway

  bmp.Save(@"theImage.bmp",ImageFormat.Bmp);//I tried only one argument but it gave a png file. Now only a black BMP

   }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120653/c-sharp-cannot-save-bitmap-to-file

Comment: You are drawing the text with a black brush. What background do you expect? If it is transparent, it is fine for PNG. BMP is a different story, so you should check if you are saving black text on a black background. Try it once with a different text color.

Comment: So I should first set the background as white? How do I do that?

Comment: What about trying a different brush for your text first? That's easier.

Comment: @j03p Checked your link. If you see the code you will see that I am already doing that link solution and does not work. Not a duplicate

Comment: @KansaiRobot - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502365/how-to-create-1024x1024-rgb-bitmap-image-of-white and adapt the size to your needs.

Comment: To fill the Bitmap with color use thegraphics.Clear(color). To draw text do use TextRenderer(), which will also allow you to specify a backcolor if you want to. Saving a PNg is usually better, but that is up to your needs.

Comment: @Sefe I tried it and you are absolutely right! The problem is the background. Thanks! ( I have some other questions regarding format but will research those from now on)

Comment: You should put your graphics object in a using(...) {...} block to correctly clean up its locked memory resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why PNG works and BMP doesn't is that PNG allows transparency in the image. In BMP the transparent parts of your image are rendered black (since it has to drop the alpha channel). Your text is also using a black brush, so you will get a black image.

For on-screen rendering this is not an issue, since there, transparency is supported.